# XE7 iOS Deploy UUID Error

Tags: ios, firemonkey, uuid, delphi-xe7

I am getting this error:

> Please specify exact device preset UUID

when I deploy to iOS 9.2 on iPhone 6 simulator.
What is that and how can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The UUID, Universally Unique IDentifier, is a number that identifies the app on a specific phone.
For some reason, FireMonkey doesn't have this number, or doesn't have it anymore.

There is an easy way to solve this. In RAD Studio, go to `Project Manager` -> `Target Platforms` -> [the platform you're working on] -> `Target`.
Right-click "Target" and choose "Refresh".

This solved the problem for me, I found this solution at: http://codeverge.com/embarcadero.delphi.firemonkey/xe8-iphone-simulator-problem/2032054